# Abstract Algebra. Polynomial division problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

> Let $k,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2 \leq k+1 < n < m$ and $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k \in \mathbb{C}$.
>
> Let $g = a_0 + a_1X + \dots + a_kX^k + X^m$ and   $f = a_0 + a_1X + \dots + a_kX^k + X^n$ and suppose $f$ divides $g$.
>
> Show that $a_0 a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k = 0$.

This is what I tried:

If $f \mid g$ then $f \mid g - f = X^m - X^n = X^n(X^{m-n} - 1)$ So if $f$ has $0$ as a root then $a_0$ will be $0$ and hence the result. So if we assume $f$ doesn't have a $0$ root then $f \mid X^{m-n} - 1$, so $f$ contains only roots of unity.

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: Looking at the $a_k$ they're elementary symmetric polynomials in the roots of unity,  which are thus sums of roots of unity.  It's well-known that roots of unity add up to zero.

Comment: Counterexample $\ 1+x+x^2\mid 1+x+x^5\ \ $

Comment: k+1<n and you have k=1 and n=2

Comment: in some sense Can you expand on that idea?

Comment: Why are the x's capitalised ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have observed, $f|g\Leftrightarrow f|(g-f)=X^n(X^{m-n} - 1)\Leftrightarrow$
$\{\text{roots of $f$}\}\subseteq \{\text{roots of $X^n(X^{m-n} - 1)$}\}=\{0,\omega,\omega^2,\cdots,\omega^{m-n}=1\}$,
where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m-n}}$.
If $0$ is a root of $f$, then $a_0=0$. We are going to prove that if $0$ is not admitted as a root of $f$, then $a_1=0$.

In fact, if $f(0)\ne 0$, then $f=(X-x_1)\cdots(X-x_n)$, where $x_i=\omega^{b_i}$ for some $1\le b_i\le m-n$ for each $1\le i\le n$.
The hypothesis that $a_{n-1}=0$ implies $x_1+\cdots+x_n=0$
\begin{equation*}
\Rightarrow \overline{x_1+\cdots+x_n}=0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n}=0  
\end{equation*}
Writing the last equation as $\frac{{\rm numerator}}{x_1\cdots x_n}=0$,
you will find the numerator is $a_1$ up to a $\pm$ sign, as desired.